# The canplay/canplaythrough events for an HTML5 video are not called on Firefox. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm building a jQuery plugin for managing HTML5 videos. I'm trying to capture the canplay and canplaythrough events. In Chrome, the event is fired without problem. In Firefox, sometime it's triggered, sometime it's not.

I'm simplifying my code a little here:

```
$('#my_video').on('canplay canplaythrough', function(){
    console.log('canplay event fired');
});
```

I also tried with the native javascript .addEventListener() and it's not working.

Any idea why the event is not called on Firefox and how to fix that?

NOTE: Please do not tell me to use one of the already available plugins like jplayer and video-js, I know that they exist and work well, but I have to build an in-house solution.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The problem is that your `video` element has triggered the `canplaythrough` event before you registered the event handler.

As you pointed out in your own answer, you can put your scripts in the `<head>`, but this is bad for your page performance.

A better way to fix your problem is to check the `readystate` attribute and execute your function manually in that case:

```
var $video = $('video'),
    videoElement = $video[0];

$video.on('canplaythrough', callback);

// If the video is in the cache of the browser,
// the 'canplaythrough' event might have been triggered
// before we registered the event handler.
if (videoElement.readyState > 3) {
  callback();
}
```

Comment: Best answer! Check the video readystate, and add the event listener if readyState isn't `4` or higher.

Comment: Amazing answer!This is the one. Thank you!!!! @Gabriel you should mark this as the answer for sure

Comment: Putting scripts not in the head is bad for: writing scripts overall and shows a lack of not comprehending standards: use the `defer` attribute, keep scripts in the head and still have the same performance.

Comment: @John: I am pretty sure that adding the `<script>` tag to the `<head>` with a `defer` will result in the same problem, that @Gabriel was describing.

Comment: No, you *always* keep scripts in the head element and *then* fix the problem. Moving scripts to the `body` element is bad practice and even considering moving the scripts between the `body` and `head` element is a clear since of amateur level understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: @john: No! There are no rules. Depending on what browsers you need to support, your approach might be the right one, or the bad one. This being said, no matter if you put your script in the head with a defer or not, the problem might occur. And in that case, my answer solves that problem. See https://github.com/h5bp/lazyweb-requests/issues/42

Answer (score 11):

The most likely reason you're seeing this probably has to do with timing issues. You stated in your accepted answer that putting jQuery into the head rather than the footer solves the problem. This tells me that the issue is DOM parsing and script execution order. The most likely culprit is that the "canplay" and "canplaythrough" events were being fired before jquery and your page script were parsed and the event handlers added - but only sometimes, depending on network traffic and load times. By putting the script in the head, you forced your event binding to occur before the DOM elements were created, thereby ensuring that you didn't miss any events.

As an aside, the performance benefits of putting script elements at the bottom of the page are debatable. If you really want to tweak page performance, use something like LABjs to manage parallel script loading.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, this was determined by the `preload` attribute specified for the element.  I did not have it specified at all, so different browsers were choosing to do different things.

Once I specified `preload="auto"`, the `on("canplay")` event handler worked fine/as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Even if my question didn't get any attention whatsoever, I think it's a good idea to give an explanation for people who may stumble on this in the future...

The problem is really weird: if the jQuery core is included in the footer, some of the video events do not work. If the jQuery core is included in the head of the document, all events are called correctly.

So the solution is to include the jQuery core in the html head even if "best practices" for optimization recommends placing all script at the end of the body for faster loading times.

Comment: I would wager its actually a race-condition, and the `canplay` and `canplaythrough` events are being fired _before_ jQuery attaches the event listeners. EDIT: Just noticed that Clayton Gulick discussed the issue below.

Comment: Or you can use javascript to hook up the event listeners, then programatically set the src attribute of the video. You can store the src in a data-src attribute, then run `videoElement.src = videoElement.dataset['src']`.

Answer (score 4):

If you expect the Firefox to load the whole audio after you trigger `load` then it would not do this. It will fire the `loadstart` but will not download anything. No `progress` events will be fired. And it will actually do no request to that file. You can see this behavior in the Firebug.

Firefox will only start loading the file after you trigger 'play`.

[Proof](http://jsbin.com/wenukugedo/6/). See console output.

Comment: actually, this behaviour is expected and can be controlled with the preload attribute on the video

Comment: @NamanGoel `The preload attribute specifies if and how the author thinks that the audio file should be loaded when the **page loads**.` As far as I can get it the `preload` has nothing to do with `audio.load()`. Instead it changes the browser behavior when no action is performed with the audio. If I am mistaking please point me to the documentation. Is it possible to force the audio NOT to load when page loads and instead to load completely when `load()` is triggered?

Comment: I can't fine a link right now. But from what I know, the browser is not supposed to load the audio unless played unless it has the `preload` attr. Some browsers preload audio/video anyway to seem fast.

Answer (score 3):

I do also think this is a race condition.  The way I got around it is as follows:

In the HTML of the video element add the attribute preload="metadata" - to just preload the video metadata.  So:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="480" preload="metadata" />
```

Next, inside the JS:

```
var $vid = $("#myVideo");
$vid.bind("canplaythrough", console.log("can play through full video"));
$vid.get(0).load();
```

This logged the message for me in Chrome - haven't tested elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Adding:

```
var video = $('video');
video.trigger('load');
```

**After** adding the canplaythrough event listener fixed it for me on Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

After 1.5 days of trying different approaches from here (in vanilla). The events "canplay" and "canplaythrough"  with addEventListner don't work in Edge. They work fine in every other Browser. So I ended up with a check of "ready-state" with setTimout :-(. Not realy elegant, but it works for me.

```
Controller.prototype.backGroundControl = function () {
var vid = document.querySelector('#bgvid');
var bgImg = document.querySelector('#bgimg');
_this = this;

if (vid.readyState === 4){
    bgImg.style.opacity = "0"
} else{
    setTimeout(function(){
        _this.backGroundControl();
    },500)
}
```

}