# jQuery placement of false on .on('canplaythrough')

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm trying to create a custom audio control and having some issues with jQuery. I'm translating this native javascript to jQuery to have a uniform code but I cannot find the way to make this work with jquery.

This is the code to change into jQuery which works fine:

```
music.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
        duration = music.duration;
    }, false);
```

This is what I have tried with no success:

tryout 1

```
music.on('canplaythrough', function (){
        duration = music.duration;
    }, false);
```

tryout 2

```
music.on('canplaythrough', function (){
        duration = music.duration;
        return false;
    });
```

tryout 3

```
music.on('canplaythrough', function (){
        duration = music.duration;
        false;
    });
```

tryout 4

```
music.on('canplaythrough', false, function (){
        duration = music.duration;
    });
```

I would like to learn how this works as I make things work but not fully understand it. For now it does not work. If somebody knows the answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: does this give you any insights   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235919/the-canplay-canplaythrough-events-for-an-html5-video-are-not-called-on-firefox    If so please post any resolution - cheers

Comment: @ScottStensland Nope, this do not answer my answer, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Is `music` a jQuery object? You might want to try `$(music).on` instead

Comment: At this moment I have this: var music = $element.find('[data-music]'); $element is the result of a .each loop which selects all the parents elements. [data-music] is inside this $element, So I suppose once selected it becomes a jQuery object right?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or something? Might be easier that way.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried my best to resume my issue. The issue is more about the syntax and how the placement of false than the context where it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

music[0].duration

[0] refers to the child element of the music element.

```
<music>
     <source src="https://music...."></source>
</music>
```