# Loader in HTML5 video not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I am trying to add a `preloader` when the video is loading using `jquery`.The problem is that it is working in every browser except `Safari`.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fhtztxwa/)

Here is the code.

```js
 $('#video_id').on('loadstart', function(event) {
   $(this).addClass('loading');
 });
 $('#video_id').on('canplay', function(event) {
   $(this).removeClass('loading');
   $(this).attr('poster', '');
 });
```

```css
video.loading {
  background: black url(http://www.drivethrurpg.com/shared_images/ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video controls="" poster="http://www.drivethrurpg.com/shared_images/ajax-loader.gif">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, the `video`-element doesnt have the `#video_id`-id. Second, you’re using a poster with the loader which means that the background image wont be seen if the placeholder is displayed above it. I see the loading poster in safari.

I updated the code with the correct id on the video.

```js
 $('#video_id').on('loadstart', function(event) {
   $(this).addClass('loading');
 });
 $('#video_id').on('canplay', function(event) {
   $(this).removeClass('loading');
   $(this).attr('poster', '');
 });
```

```css
video.loading {
  background: black url(http://www.drivethrurpg.com/shared_images/ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video_id" controls="" poster="http://www.drivethrurpg.com/shared_images/ajax-loader.gif">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and correcting my mistake,but still the code is not working in Safari

Comment: What isn’t working? Both the poster and the background images works fine for me. I’m using `Safari 10.0.3`. Are you talking about Safari on iOS or macOS?

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 in IOS.

Comment: This might be the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235919/the-canplay-canplaythrough-events-for-an-html5-video-are-not-called-on-firefox Your video element has triggered the canplay event before you registered the event handler