# canplay even doesn't fire on Cached videos sources in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-video

I'm having an issue with Vue and Chrome. I have a video element which I dynamically change the src and then have an event fire once it is loaded I have it set up like this

```
<video :src="videoFile" @canplay="videoLoadedFunction">
```

This works fine the first time, and the canplay function fires. However, this app is operating on a loop, and when the src changes to a video that was already played, the canplay event never fires. I believe it's because the video is already cached.

I have a work around solution for the time being, just adding a random number as a query to the videofiles URL, but this makes the app redownload the videos every time. I'm wondering if there is a more proper way to fire the canplay event for cached videos?

Comment: Have you tried manually checking the readyState? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235919/the-canplay-canplaythrough-events-for-an-html5-video-are-not-called-on-firefox

Comment: didn't consider that! Thank you. I will add a listener to the videoFile prop, and check for the ready state of the video when the prop changes. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @yuriy636 is it possible to set a listener on the readyState prop? Or am I better off putting a listener on the source URL variable, and checking the ready state of the video after that changes? Should I wait a tick before checking?