# Fade out preloader on canplaythrough ist working only sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video

I would like to fade out a preloader div as soon as a short fullscreen HTML5 video can be expected to play smooth without further buffering. The preloader is a div covering the whole viewport, the fade out is done by CSS when jQuery adds class 'fadeout' to the preloader. Out of all HTMLMediaElement events 'canplaythrough' seems to be the best fit for my needs, though I know that 'canplaythrough' is only an assumption.

My code basically works but unfortunately not always. I can't detect a unambiguous system – Chrome and Safari seem to have fewer problems than Firefox and reloading the page seems to do different things than an uncached loading:

```html
<body>

<div id='preloader'></div>
<!-- other HTML -->
<video id='startvideo' src='foo.mp4' poster='foo.jpg' autoplay loop muted></video>
<!-- other HTML -->

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#startvideo").on("canplaythrough", function(event) { 
            $("#preloader").addClass("fadeout");
            console.log("preloader faded out");
        }); 
    });
</script>

</body>
```

I found [this older thread discussing an at least similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235919/the-canplay-canplaythrough-events-for-an-html5-video-are-not-called-on-firefox). The chosen answer suggests it has to do with the loading order and hence should be solved with a callback function, but I don’t know how to do that in the given context. So I would appreciate any help on this issue.